# Php search for specific links and append the url after them

Tags: php

I have a string following the patterns

```
$mystring="bla <a href="website.com"></a>";
```

with few more links and other html tags.

I want to use a php function to:

- Search for all the href tags that contain a specific word. In this case, the word would be `website.com`.
- Append a text link with the same URL to every occurrence.

**Example:**

```
<a href="website.com?bla"></a>
```

Should become to:

```
<a href="website.com?bla"></a><br><a href="website.com?bla">New link here</a>
```

And the same goes for the rest links.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: i didn't get your question...

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should iterate around all occurrences, using `strpos` method, using the `lastPos` as offset. Then insert the string/new link, after finding the closing

```
$needle = "website.com?"; // word to find
$endLink = "</a>"
$lastPos = 0;
$str_to_insert = "<br><a href=\"website.com?bla\">New link here</a>" // text to append

while (($lastPos = strpos($mystring, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    //position just after finding the string is: occurrence + string length
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
    //finding the end of link (to append it there)
    $writePos = strpos($mystring, $endLink, $lastPos);
    //appending the string and updating $mystring
    $mystring = substr_replace($mystring, $str_to_insert, $writePos, strlen($endLink);
    //add the appended string to lastPos, to avoid searching it
    $lastPos = $writePos + strlen($str_to_insert)

}
```

**EDIT**

Making `$str_to_insert` dynamic:

```
while (($lastPos = strpos($mystring, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
        $str_to_insert = substr($mystring, $lastPos, len($needle)
        //position just after finding the string is: occurrence + string length
        $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
        // ... the rest keeps the same
}
```

Comment: Looks okay, but the str_to_insert actually should be dynamic, meaning it should get the current link URL and use it to create the new link right after it.

Comment: @prav I have just edited the answer. Hope you accepted if that works for you :)